# How can I add a changing integer variable to string?

Tags: c++, c++11

There is something wrong in the if condition but it's the 7th day I have no clue. It prints the taken integer like this

> mike .. mike1 .. mike12 .. mike123

But actually I need it to be like this

> mike .. mike1 .. mike2 .. mike3

Can anyone help? this is my code :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

string str(int o){
stringstream ss;
ss<<o;
return ss.str();}

int main(){

int n;
cin>>n;
int z[n];
for(int p=0;p<n;p++)
{
    z[p]=-50;
}
string x[n];
int k;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    k=1;
    cin>>x[i];
    for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
        if(x[j]== x[i]){
            x[i] = x[j] + str(k) ;
            k++;
            z[i]=0;
        }
    }
}

for(int q=0;q<n;q++){
    if(z[q]==0)
        cout<<x[q]<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"OK"<<endl;
}
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is a syntax error,the double star before for and later. Check it.

Comment: i know the stars before and later but i put them so you can see that part of code clearly

Comment: IMO this second loop is useless and this is the real culprit

Comment: Any suggestion of how to solve it ?

Comment: To mark it, use a comment and anyone can compile it easily. Don't use error constructs

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second `for` loop and get `k` outside the loop like this:

```
 k=1;

  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

    cin>>x[i];         
    x[i] = x[i] + str(k) ;
    k++;
    z[i]=0;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify all your code with `C++11`

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, k = 1;
    cin >> n;
    vector<bool> z(n, false);
    vector<string> x(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cin >> x[i];
        x[i] += to_string(k);
        ++k;
        z[i] = true;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        cout << (z[i] ? x[i] : "OK") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Meyer perhaps you can accept and upvote the answer if problem solved.

Comment: thank you that made it way easier but that part didn't work and gave me compilation error `to_string(k)` I don't know what is wrong with this function

Comment: @Meyer I mentioned C++11 but it seems you forgot the compilation flag `-std=c++11`.

Comment: @Meyer Did you compile with C++11 flag ? what did you get ?

Comment: the same output mike1 .. mike12 .. mike123 .. mike1234 :(

Comment: @Meyer OK this means, the code works perfectly as expected.

Comment: @Meyer, See http://ideone.com/zjzUbZ, I get output as your question expects. How are you running it or giving input ?